# misunderstanding of Boolean result

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Can somebody help me a bit? I have trouble understanding why Boolean here doesn't work the way I want to. The idea is when `i`(firstnum) is odd, `l`(lastnum) to be equal and vice verse. Some help with how to use Boolean also will be a help, I can't understand it.

Input 3 and 5.

Expected output : 4333 4353 4443 4533 4553 5334 5354 5444 5534 5554

Actual output: 4333 4353 4443 4533 4553 5333 5334 5353 5354 5443 5444 5533 5534 5553 5554

```
int startNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
int endNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

boolean isItEqual = false;
boolean isItOdd= false;

int countDebugOperations = 0;
for (int i = startNum; i <=endNum ; i++) {

    if (i % 2==0){
        isItEqual =true;
    }
    for (int j = startNum; j <=endNum ; j++) {
        for (int k = startNum; k <=endNum ; k++) {
            for (int l = startNum; l <=endNum ; l++) {
                if (l % 2 == 1){
                    isItOdd = true;
                }
                boolean flag =(i > l) && (j+k) % 2 ==0;

                if(!isItEqual && (!isItOdd) && flag){

                        countDebugOperations+=1;
                        System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d ",i,j,k,l);

                }
                if (isItEqual && isItOdd && flag) {
                    countDebugOperations += 1;
                    System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d ", i, j, k, l);

                }
```

Comment: Could you add: input, actual output and expected output to the question? lastnum has to be equal to what?

Comment: Yes , input 3 and 5

Comment: Expected output : 4333 4353 4443 4533 4553 5334 5354 5444 5534 5554

Comment: Actual output: 4333 4353 4443 4533 4553 5333 5334 5353 5354 5443 5444 5533 5534 5553 5554

Comment: If first number is odd last number has to be even, if last number is odd, first number has to be even :( Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let me clarify, you want to print `i`, `j`, `k` and `l` only when `i` and `l` have different parity?

Comment: Yes, for example if  **i  == 2** - **l==3**  and if **i==3** **l==2**,only then i wanna print :(

Comment: Check  :  isItEqual && isItOdd at my code

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to print numbers `i`, `j`, `k` and `l` in exactly two cases:

1. When `i` is even **AND** `l` is odd
2. When `l` is even **AND** `i` is odd

If we translate those cases to code (boolean expressions), we get:

1. `i % 2 == 0 && l % 2 == 1`
2. `l % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 1`

Now, when we iterate through `for` loops, we can ask if our "number state" matches one of those 2 cases (first case **OR** second case).

```
int startNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
int endNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

for (int i = startNum; i <= endNum; i++) {
    for (int j = startNum; j <= endNum; j++) {
        for (int k = startNum; k <= endNum; k++) {
            for (int l = startNum; l <= endNum; l++) {

                boolean firstCase = i % 2 == 0 && l % 2 == 1;
                boolean secondCase = l % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 1;

                // now when we print, we can ask if we are in the first OR the second case
                if (firstCase || secondCase) {
                    System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d ",i,j,k,l);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```